# SVG and Canvas, cross-platform web application

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, canvas, svg

I'm building an UI for rich web application which should work equally well on desktops and smartphones. Interface contains some non-rectangular elements and curved lines so it couldn't be made with common html. Also there are icons (originally presented as SVG) and some complex effects (shadows, blurring etc.).

SVG is the best choice but as far as I know, Android built-in browser does not support it. On the other hand, canvas could be faster but here comes problems with effects implementation, events generating and inability to select/copy text.

It's possible to make independent implementation for both cases and select best one at runtime, but support and further development of such a system could become a real headache. I'm thinking of intermediate abstract layer which could connect to SVG or Canvas renderer. Searching for ready solutions did not succeed.

I'm new to GUI programming so my question is: what is best practices for such abstraction framework?

Comment: Like Fusion Charts where flash is not supported on iOS the chart components fallback to JS charts(Highcharts). These kind of ideas may inspire you... :)